# Value stored in shared NSUserDefaults or shared keychain is not updated in time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, keychain, userdefaults

I try to share some data between my app and it's notification extension. I setup an App Group and use NSUserDefaults to share the data. It works fine at the beginning. But then i found when i update the value from A to B, the extension will not get the updated value, from the extension's perspective the value remains to be A. The value is not updated until I relaunch my app, this is not how i expected the data to be shared.

I tried 'synchronize' on NSUserDefaults.(i know this api is deprecated). Not working.
I tried to use keychain access group and store data with keychain. But it seems like the item in keychain is also not updated in time.

```c
//  save value in my app

- (void)onButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *groupUserDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"myAppGroup"];
    [groupUserDefaults setObject:@"A" forKey:@"key"];
}
...

//  read value from notification extension

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    NSUserDefaults *groupUserDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"myAppGroup"];
    NSString *value = [groupUserDefaults stringForKey:@"key"];

    // modify notification content

    self.contentHandler(modifiedContent)
}
```

I need to share data between my app and notification extension in real time other than synchronized once per launch (as I observed). Really need some advice.

Comment: Can you provide some more context for the code... in which function are you retrieving the user defaults.

Comment: Have you tried `[yourNSUserDefaultsInstance synchronize]` after setting each value?

Comment: @Kamil.S yes i tried

Comment: @Paulw11 sure, edited